# Electron interaction term in a external field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

In quantum electrodynamics an electron $e_0$ interaction with an external field is given by  term

$\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}\sim  \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu A_{\mu}^{c}\psi$

Where $A_{\mu}^{c}$ is  classical field.

Texts books never justify why is it so but for me, this  term is justified if we split the electromagnetic potential $A_{\mu}$ into

$A=A^0+A^{c}$

assuming that $A_{\mu}^0$ is very small and $A_{\mu}^{c}$ is an operator satisfying

$< \Box A^{c}>=<j>$

Here  is $<j>$ a electromagnetic current due to some $n$ particles whose configurations is not affected by the electron $e_0$ and the expectation value is made in some state that coincide with what we measure in space.

Can we deduce these interaction $ \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu A_{\mu}^{c}\psi$  term from scattering of the electron $e_0$  into a bunch of $n$ electrons $e_1,..e_n$ using the formalism of quantum field theory? If it so how?